# JS calculator issue. Wrong Answer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a one-line calculator, that has the basic functions (+ - * /). I have done this before, but now I keep getting wrong answers, and I can't find my mistake. Here is my code:

```
var seq = document.getElementById('sequence').value;
var allNums = [];
var i = 0, allSigns = [];
var currentNums = "";

for (i = 0; i< seq.length; i++)
{
    if (seq[i] != "+" && seq[i] != "-" && seq[i] != "*" && seq[i] != "/")
    {
        currentNums+=seq[i];
    }
    else
    {
        allNums.push(Number(currentNums));
        currentNums="";
        allSigns.push(seq[i]);
    }
}
allNums.push(Number(currentNums));
var result = 0;
for (i = 0; i < allNums.length; i++)
{
    if (allSigns[i] == '+')
        result+=Number(allNums[i]);
    else if (allSigns[i] == "-")
        result-=Number(allNums[i]);
    else if (allSigns[i] == "*")
        result*=Number(allNums[i]);
    else if (allSigns[i] == "/")
        result/=parseInt(allNums[i]);
    else
    {
        alert("The result is: " + result);
        break;
    }
}
```

All of this code is in a function, called calculate. The func is triggered by a button, and the sequence comes from an input.

Comment: How come one of them uses parseInt and the others Number?

Comment: What kinds of errors are you getting? Can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: Just to try if the problem comes from there. There is no difference if all are with Number(), or parseInt(). Well there is no actual error, only the answer is wrong.

Comment: One line js calculator: `alert("The answer is " + eval(prompt("Input:")));`

Comment: I know about eval, but I'm not allowed to use it :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/obasix/3/edit

There are not as many signs as numbers.  So therefore, if there are 2 numbers and 1 sign, it will calculate 5 + and then end.

You should start with the result bring the first number.

And then iterate with the remaining numbers and calculate accordingly.

```
var seq = "5+4";
var allNums = [];
var i = 0, allSigns = [];
var currentNums = "";

for (i = 0; i< seq.length; i++)
{
    if (seq[i] != "+" && seq[i] != "-" && seq[i] != "*" && seq[i] != "/")
    {
        currentNums+=seq[i];
    }
    else
    {
        allNums.push(Number(currentNums));
        currentNums="";
        allSigns.push(seq[i]);
    }
}
allNums.push(Number(currentNums));

var result = allNums[0];
for (i = 1; i <= allNums.length; i++)
{
    if (allSigns[i-1] == '+')
        result+=Number(allNums[i]);
    else if (allSigns[i-1] == "-")
        result-=Number(allNums[i]);
    else if (allSigns[i-1] == "*")
        result*=Number(allNums[i]);
    else if (allSigns[i-1] == "/")
        result/=parseInt(allNums[i]);
    else
    {
        alert("The result is: " + result);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man that worked great. With your code and explanation and @jmeas's one I understood what I was doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Though there are numerous shortcomings with this simple calculator that may or may not be a problem (depending on what you want to do with it), one issue is that your `allSigns` array values aren't being associated with the correct `allNums` array values.

Take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/8b6BH/). In the console, you can see that the sign associated with the `6` is the plus sign, while the operator associated with `2` is undefined. This isn't what we want, of course. What we want is to add the two to the six.

The fix for this issue would be always adding `allNums[0]` to the `result` from the start. This sets up our result to be operated upon by anything following it. In this case, we start off with `6`.

Next what we need to do is shift the position of each value of `allSigns` down by one, lining up the operator with the value *after* it, and not *before* it. So, in the example above, we'd have `+` associated with `2`, so it'd add the two to the six.

[**This JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8b6BH/1/) shows the fix for this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library https://github.com/notshekhar/calculate.js

### Example

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notshekhar/calculate.js/main/calculate.js"></script>
<script>
  let add = calculate(1, 1, "+") // add -> 2
  let sub = calculate(1, 1, "-") // sub -> 0
  let mul = calculate(1, 1, "*") // mul -> 1
  let div = calculate(1, 1, "/") // div -> 1
  let mod = calculate(1, 1, "%") // mod -> 0
</script>
```